# Making a list from items at n position

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a nested list using data from other lists. I want to make a list where the n items from other lists are at n position in the outer list.

```
red = [1, 2, 3]
green = [4, 5, 6]
blue = [7, 8, 9]
```

What I tried doing:

```
index= []
[index.append(n)for n in (red, green, blue)]   
print(index)
```

What I got:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

What I want:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Hint: Use `zip`

Comment: Or use numpy- for example: `np.array([red, green, blue]).T.tolist()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need is this:

```
list(map(list, zip(red, green, blue)))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[list(l) for l in zip(red, green, blue)]
```

which returns:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```